# WPF StringFormat Designer error

Tags: wpf

I made a MultiBind Converter to format a TextBlock into a template. One dependency property "StringFormat" was created for the user to define the format the text will appear in the TextBlock. The other property (Value) already exists in the parent object. The codes are as follows:

** XAML **

```
<TextBlock
    x:Name="myText">
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource StringFormatConverter}">
            <Binding Path="Value" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
            <Binding Path="StringFormat" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

** C# **

```
public class StringFormatConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(
        object[] value,
        Type targetType,
        object parameter,
        CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string val = string.Empty;

        if (value[1] != null)
        {
            val = (string)(value[1].ToString());
            return String.Format(culture, val, value[0]);
        }
        else return value[0];
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(
        object value,
        Type[] targetTypes,
        object parameter,
        CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

When I run the application, it runs without errors, and the passed format string works as expected. However, in designer mode, it displays the following message:

> XamlParseException: Input string was not in a correct format.
>
> StackTrace
>
> at System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadTemplateXaml(XamlReader
>   templateReader, XamlObjectWriter currentWriter) at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadTemplateXaml(XamlObjectWriter
>   objectWriter) at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadOptimizedTemplateContent(DependencyObject
>   container, IComponentConnector componentConnector, IStyleConnector
>   styleConnector, List`1 affectedChildren, UncommonField`1
>   templatedNonFeChildrenField) at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.LoadContent(DependencyObject
>   container, List`1 affectedChildren) at
>   System.Windows.StyleHelper.ApplyTemplateContent(UncommonField`1
>   dataField, DependencyObject container, FrameworkElementFactory
>   templateRoot, Int32 lastChildIndex, HybridDictionary
>   childIndexFromChildID, FrameworkTemplate frameworkTemplate)    at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.ApplyTemplateContent(UncommonField`1
>   templateDataField, FrameworkElement container)    at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ApplyTemplate()
>
> InnerException: Input string was not in a correct format.
>
> FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
>
> StackTrace
>
> at System.Text.StringBuilder.AppendFormat(IFormatProvider provider,
>   String format, Object[] args)    at
>   System.String.Format(IFormatProvider provider, String format, Object[]
>   args)    at
>   Ipiranga.WPF.Componentes.Componentes.StringFormatConverter.Convert(Object[]
>   value, Type targetType, Object parameter, CultureInfo culture)    at
>   System.Windows.Data.MultiBindingExpression.TransferValue()    at
>   System.Windows.Data.MultiBindingExpression.Transfer()    at
>   System.Windows.Data.MultiBindingExpression.UpdateTarget(Boolean
>   includeInnerBindings)    at
>   System.Windows.Data.MultiBindingExpression.AttachToContext(Boolean
>   lastChance)    at
>   System.Windows.Data.MultiBindingExpression.AttachOverride(DependencyObject
>   d, DependencyProperty dp)    at
>   System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.OnAttach(DependencyObject d,
>   DependencyProperty dp)    at
>   System.Windows.StyleHelper.GetInstanceValue(UncommonField`1 dataField,
>   DependencyObject container, FrameworkElement feChild,
>   FrameworkContentElement fceChild, Int32 childIndex, DependencyProperty
>   dp, Int32 i, EffectiveValueEntry& entry)    at
>   System.Windows.StyleHelper.GetChildValueHelper(UncommonField`1
>   dataField, ItemStructList`1& valueLookupList, DependencyProperty dp,
>   DependencyObject container, FrameworkObject child, Int32 childIndex,
>   Boolean styleLookup, EffectiveValueEntry& entry, ValueLookupType&
>   sourceType, FrameworkElementFactory templateRoot)    at
>   System.Windows.StyleHelper.GetChildValue(UncommonField`1 dataField,
>   DependencyObject container, Int32 childIndex, FrameworkObject child,
>   DependencyProperty dp, FrugalStructList`1& childRecordFromChildIndex,
>   EffectiveValueEntry& entry, ValueLookupType& sourceType,
>   FrameworkElementFactory templateRoot)    at
>   System.Windows.StyleHelper.GetValueFromTemplatedParent(DependencyObject
>   container, Int32 childIndex, FrameworkObject child, DependencyProperty
>   dp, FrugalStructList`1& childRecordFromChildIndex,
>   FrameworkElementFactory templateRoot, EffectiveValueEntry& entry)
>   at
>   System.Windows.StyleHelper.ApplyTemplatedParentValue(DependencyObject
>   container, FrameworkObject child, Int32 childIndex,
>   FrugalStructList`1& childRecordFromChildIndex, DependencyProperty dp,
>   FrameworkElementFactory templateRoot)    at
>   System.Windows.StyleHelper.InvalidatePropertiesOnTemplateNode(DependencyObject
>   container, FrameworkObject child, Int32 childIndex,
>   FrugalStructList`1& childRecordFromChildIndex, Boolean isDetach,
>   FrameworkElementFactory templateRoot)    at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.InvalidatePropertiesOnTemplate(DependencyObject
>   container, Object currentObject)    at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.HandleBeforeProperties(Object
>   createdObject, DependencyObject& rootObject, DependencyObject
>   container, FrameworkElement feContainer, INameScope nameScope)    at
>   System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate.<>c__DisplayClass6.b__3(Object
>   sender, XamlObjectEventArgs args)    at
>   System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.OnBeforeProperties(Object value)    at
>   System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.Logic_CreateAndAssignToParentStart(ObjectWriterContext
>   ctx)    at System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriter.WriteStartMember(XamlMember
>   property)    at System.Xaml.XamlWriter.WriteNode(XamlReader reader)

What am I doing wrong, since the code runs and works properly? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'd have to guess that your safety check is bad. Don't check for value[x] != null, use the as keyword:

```
string strVal = value[1] as string;
```

Reason being is you probably aren't getting null, but rather DependencyProperty.UnsetValue.